# Does Visual Studio for Mac 17.5.7 (build 6) support hot reloading?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I'm running a .NET Core 7 project on Visual Studio for Mac v17.5.7 (build 6) and for the life of me can't find a way to enable hot reloading. It's so straightforward in the windows app but I've looked everywhere: Project configurations and Preferences and can't find any toggle to enable/disable it.

There's a known issue on their page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/mac-release-notes-preview but when you click the link to "Hot Reload setting page is blank" it throws a 403.

What am I missing here or Does it just not exist?

I checked the Visual studio documentation and release notes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/mac-release-notes-preview

And as mentioned above checked every possible configuration window available.

Comment: That 'Hot Reload setting page is blank' seems to be an internal feedback ticket, not sure why that is. It is also about XAML Hot Reload, not .NET Hot Reload. There are several different types of Hot Reload. XAML Hot Reload is supported, other types are not currently supported in Visual Studio for Mac. XAML Hot Reload settings are available in Preferences - Other - XAML Hot Reload.